# Probability and supremum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Problem:

Suppose $X_1,......,X_n.....$ are independent random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(sup_nX_n<\infty)=1$. Show that $sup_nX_n(x)<\infty$ for all $x\in \Omega$

This is a lemma I have constructed, but i'm not sure how to prove it or if a counter example exists. Intuitively, it means that the probability of the set $\{$ $sup_nX_n<\infty \}$ occuring is 100%, which would make intuitive sense to then imply that $sup_nX_n(x)<\infty$. May someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is very very false. You can always change the values of $X_i$'s on set of measure $0$ to find a point where the supremum is $\infty$.

For example let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d coin tossing random variables. Define $Y_n(x)=X_n(x)$ if $X_n(x) \neq 1$ for some $n$ and $Y_n(x)=n$ if $X_n(x) =1$ for all $n$.